# MongoDB aggregation framework to join by id two faceted collections

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following document (result of a `$facet`):

```
{
  "productProperties": [
    {
     "productId": "1"
     "productProperty": "AAA"
    },
    {
      "productId": "2"
      "productProperty": "BBB"
    },
    {
      "productId": "3"
      "productProperty": "CCC"
    }
  ],
  "productRelations": [
    {
      "productId": "1",
      "relatedProducts": [
        {
          "productId": "2",
          "relationProperty": 222
        },
        {
          "productId": "3",          
          "relationProperty": 333
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "productId": "2",
      "relatedProducts": [
        {
          "productId": "1",
          "relationProperty": 111
        }
      ]
    }      
  ]  
}
```

From the previous document and using MongoDb aggregation framework I want to build a collection enriching `productRelations` with `productProperties`.

This is, I want to add for each product the property `productProperty`. Note that the property is not added only in the root element, but also in each related product:

```
[
  {
    "productId": "1",
    "productProperty": "AAA",
    "relatedProducts": [
      {
        "productId": "2",
        "productProperty": "BBB",
        "relationProperty": 222
      },
      {
        "productId": "3",
        "productProperty": "CCC",      
        "relationProperty": 333
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "productId": "2",
    "otherField": "BBB",
    "relatedProducts": [
      {
        "productId": "1",
        "productProperty": "AAA",
        "relationProperty": 111
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I tried to use `$lookup`, but it only works with other collections and I want to do this aggregation in situ.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run nested [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) with [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) to "join" two collections. The problem is that getting first element and it's subproperty has a bit cumbersome syntax but you can use [$let](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/let/index.html) to run it as one big expression. Then you just need to run [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get your expected result:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            productRelations: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$productRelations",
                    as: "pr",
                    in: {
                        productId: "$$pr.productId",
                        productProperty: {
                            $let: {
                                vars: { 
                                    match: { 
                                        $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$productProperties", cond: { $eq: [ "$$pr.productId", "$$this.productId" ] } } }, 0 ] 
                                    } 
                                },
                                in: "$$match.productProperty"
                            }
                        },
                        relatedProducts: {
                            $map: {
                                input: "$$pr.relatedProducts",
                                as: "rp",
                                in: {
                                    productId: "$$rp.productId",
                                    relationProperty: "$$rp.relationProperty",
                                    productProperty: {
                                        $let: {
                                            vars: { 
                                                match: { 
                                                    $arrayElemAt: [ { $filter: { input: "$productProperties", cond: { $eq: [ "$$rp.productId", "$$this.productId" ] } } }, 0 ] 
                                                } 
                                            },
                                            in: "$$match.productProperty"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$productRelations"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$productRelations"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/fbStd9lsikt)